# Making a custom step graph with mpandroidchart

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mpandroidchart

I want to achieve this kind of chart using MPAndroidChart. In particular.

[image]

I have done all the necessary setup and particularly customized the chart to use the stepped mode below

```
Val set1 = LineDataSet(values, "DataSet 1");
set1.setMode(LineDataSet.Mode.STEPPED);
```

This is what I've been able to achieve so far. In particular, I want to implement the thickness of the horizontal lines and also the gradient coloring of the lines.

I'll appreciate any recommendation to achieve the desired template I attached.

[image]

Comment: What is it that you feel is missing from your current chart? The thickness of the horizontal lines? The lack of gridlines? The gradient coloring of the lines? Please update the question to be more specific about what you want.

Comment: @TylerV, thanks for the comment. I've updated the question. I hope it's clear enough